# How to change the querystring when I submit my GET form using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, get

Suppose that I have a simple form in my page like this :

```
<form action="/properties/search" method="GET" id="form_search">
  <p>
    <label for="price">Min price:</label>
    <input type="text" name="min_price" id="min_price">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="price">Max price:</label>
    <input type="text" name="max_price" id="max_price">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit">
  </p>
</form>
```

When I submit my form, I have the following url :

http://.../properties/search?min_price=100000&max_price=200000

I want to change this url to have :

http://.../properties/search?price=100000,200000

To do that, I'm using JQuery and the [JQuery querystring plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form_search").submit(function() {
        var querystring = rewrite_interval_qstring();
        // querystring equals "?price=100000,200000" -> exactly what I want !

        // ???
    });
});
```

How can I change (comment "???") the submit url ? I have tested the following instructions separately, but it does not work.

```
window.location = querystring;
window.location.href = querystring;
window.location.search = querystring;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default submit action from happening

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form_search").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // <-- add this
        var querystring = rewrite_interval_qstring();
        // querystring equals "?price=100000,200000" -> exactly what I want !

        window.location.href = querystring; // <-- this should work.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You're almost there. Intercept the submit event (as you are doing), extract the min and max values, build your url and set window.location.href

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form_search").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $this = $(this);
        // var url = rewrite_interval_qstring();
        var min_price = $('#min_price').val();
        var max_price = $('#max_price').val();
        var url = $this.attr('action') + '?price=' + min_price + ',' + max_price;
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Rob Cowie is one method. Another one is adding a hidden field named "price" and fill it before submitting it with the value you want.