# jquery validation - submitting form with enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and jquery and I'm trying to submit a form which is validated using the jquery validation plugin using the enter key. This is my code but the form is not being submitted as the alert isn't showing when you press enter. I'm not sure what exactly is happening. I think the page is simply being reloaded when i press enter. There's certainly no validation

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                 error.appendTo('#invalid_' + element.attr('id'));

                  }
        });

        var validator = $("#login_form").validate({
            rules: {
                user_email: {
                  required: true,
                  email: true

                },
                password: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages:{
                user_email:{
                    required:"Email required",
                    email: "Must be a valid email"
                },
                password: {
                    required: "Password required"
                }

            }, 


            submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert('submitted');
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/check_login.php",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                timeout: 3000,
                success: function(resp) { 
                    if (resp == 'error') {
                        $('#login_error').html('Invalid login');
                    } else {


                        load_user_area();




                    }

                },
                error: function(e) {alert('failed' + e);}
              });
              return false;
            }

        });


$(document).keydown(function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { $('#login_form').submit(); }
});

});

</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: does it submit properly when you click the actual form button?

Comment: i Suggest you to use `keyup` instead of 'keydown`

Comment: Posting your form's HTML would be helpful.  Otherwise, how do we know your selectors are correct?

Comment: Please try using `e.which` instead of `e.keycode` as this takes care of the browser compatibility issues. or even something like this `var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;`

Comment: do not recommend to use function(e) because I had a similar problem... please look or see on the my answer

Comment: Your form should automatically submit if you press enter while any of its form elements are focused. That's typically enough.

Comment: Why not simply have an onsubmit function? forms generally submit on enter.

Comment: @Mirko What do you mean, `function(e)`? That's pretty critical to event handling.

Comment: I delete my answer because I obtained the down-voted.
When I wanted change the querystring using the form inside the dialog.
I used to use   $("#formparam").submit( function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $this = $(this);
            alert("Se funziona questo mi hai aiutato");
}
 And this not working, I created the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708265/particular-case-programmed-query-string-using-form-inside-dialog for how could I program the querystring..
@passionateCoder AND meagar