# how to trigger div on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

i am newbie in jquery... just started learning it...

i stuck in one problem is when i click on **Open Model** anchor link it's triggering **Open Modal div** and it will give one popup window with content of **Open Modal div**... that code is below...

```
  <a href="#opneModal"> Open Model </a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
   <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Congrats..</h2>
    <p>Now you can apply discount.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

you can take look of output [here](http://jsbin.com/iMAzehE/1/edit)

till now everything is working fine. but now i want to open popup window (trigger **OpenModal div**) when i submit the form... the submit form code is below...

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
       <input type="text" name="name" required="" placeholder="Name" class="textbox"/>
       <input type="email" name="email" required="" placeholder="Email Address*" class="textbox"/>
      <input type="submit"  id="send" value="SUBMIT" class="button" />
    </form>

    $('form').submit(function(){
        //which code i should write which will call **OpenModal div**
    })
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$('.modalDialog').fadeIn();` will it work for you?

Comment: You spelt openModal wrong.

Comment: Excuse but I can receive information that my answer is helpful or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> till now everything is working fine. but now i want to open popup
>   window (trigger OpenModal div) when i submit the form... the submit
>   form code is below...

I think that you say of a **modal dialog**.

I created the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708265/particular-case-programmed-query-string-using-form-inside-dialog) ,
I think that I wrong the title because is difficult for search it.
I worked with method GET and I have no idea if this work with also with method POST but you can try.

Now I explain how to work.

You use this form and I say of see the action.

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="forma">
       <input type="text" name="name" required="" placeholder="Name" class="textbox"/>
       <input type="email" name="email" required="" placeholder="Email Address*" class="textbox"/>
      <input type="submit"  id="send" value="SUBMIT" class="button" />
    </form>
```

I suggest you of replace

```
<input type="submit"  id="send" value="SUBMIT" class="button" />
```

with

```
<input type="button" value="Clicca qui" onclick="start()" />
```

Because now not send the form.

I explain the **function start**

```
function start() {
var $fm = $("#forma");
                $.post($fm.attr('you action is form'))
                    .done(function(data, ok){
                    var fr=$fm.serialize();
//now you can open the window popup and you can pass the variable fr or not. the important //that you not lose this contain of variable. When you close the window you say on server or //site that you go at address.
//With document.location.href="index2?"+fr; if you site is localhost:8100/index?bla=2&l=3
//document.location is localhost:8100 and document.location.href is the part index?bla=2&l=3
//then you have to go the localhost:8100/upload (look the action) you have to use
//document.location.href="upload?"+fr; 
//now I make the action 's form with this script


                    document.location.href="index2?"+fr;
                                    })
                    .fail(function(data){
                    alert('call failed');
                    // call failed for some reason -- add error messaging?
                    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//then here is your code
$('form').submit(function(e){
        $('#openModal').fadeIn()
        e.preventDefault()
    })
```

Comment: @AdamAzad anchor link i just kept for testing.. originally i want to popup window while user submit form

Comment: see here http://jsbin.com/iMAzehE/4/edit... anchor is working.. insted of anchor i want to do samething when i submits the form

Comment: See edit above, you need to call your method, which popups the div in the jquery

Comment: i tried that same code but not working... it's directly redirecting in to my form action page...

Comment: So, you need to prevent default submit, added e.preventDefault() to the code above

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery code should go like this

```
$('form').submit( function(e) {
    $('a').trigger('click') //or open model directly
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, above approach will work. Main thing is about e.preventDefault that will cancel the default form submit.

Comment: see here http://jsbin.com/iMAzehE/4/edit... anchor is working.. insted of anchor i want to do samething when i submits the form

Answer (score 0):

I think you want (When you submit the form the `dialog` will be displayed:

```
$('#send').click(function(foo){
     foo.preventDefault(); // you can remove this if you change #send type to button

     $('form').submit(function(){ // submit the form and show the dialog
        $('#mylink').click();
     })
});
```

Comment: it's redirecting me to my form action page... it's coming inside sumbit function but it's not showing ...

Comment: change `#send` type to button `<input type="button"  id="send" value="SUBMIT" class="button" />`

Comment: when i click on sumbit button nothing happens... can you edit your code http://jsbin.com/iMAzehE/4/edit here