# Pass value from field to querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, tag-helpers

How do I set the value to the query string

```
<form asp-route="TalkMessageBoardSearch" asp-route-talk_query="[need value from "talk_query" field]" method="post" class="form" role="form">
    <input type="hidden" />
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="talk_query" name="talk_query" placeholder="Search Talk" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div> </form>
```

When the button is clicked on POST, it is redirecting to "/message_board_search" but it doesn't have the querystring. I want it to show "/message_board_search?talk_query=query1" How do I get the value from the id="talk_query" field and put it in the querystring when the POST is clicked. Right now "asp-route-talk_query" can be hardcoded like asp-route-talk_query="hardcoded"

I used the "asp-route" because the view is in /talk/message_board_search" but I want it to be in the root path "/message_board_search" so that is why I used the route "TalkMessageBoardSearch."

Comment: You need to add querystring on submit, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6087737/87956

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the < form > method attribute with POST. The "method" you specify changes the behavior:

POST method does not affect the query string

GET method affects the query string.

[HTTP Methods: GET vs. POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

[HTML < form > method Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)

If you need to use POST but *also* modify the query string to contain dynamic data, you must use Javascript. You cannot use the < form > method by itself in that case. (see Vinay's comment, he has a link for this!)